# The job is not reading Ip from proxy broker

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, selenium, proxy

I am trying to import a proxy from proxy broker into Selenium with Python.

This tends to work; however it seems I have to manually input the proxy each time and when I use:

```
PROXY = " proxies" # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT
```

It tends to create problems and not load correctly.

It prints out:

```
Found proxy: <Proxy CI 0.79s [HTTPS] 213.136.105.62:80>
```

I can’t find any documentation to circumvent this issue.  I have used Regex to try and circumvent this but it seems the same issue happens regardless.

The browser will often launch but then not navigate anywhere because the proxy does not seem to load correctly.

```
mport asyncio
from proxybroker import Broker

async def show(proxies):
    while True:
        proxy = await proxies.get()
        if proxy is None: break
        print('Found proxy: %s' % proxy)

proxies = asyncio.Queue()
broker = Broker(proxies)
tasks = asyncio.gather(
    broker.find(types=['HTTPS', 'HTTPS'], limit=1),
    show(proxies))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(tasks)
#185.106.121.97:1080>
#185.82.203.188:1080

#185.106.121.97

#Output: Found proxy: <Proxy CI 0.79s [HTTPS] 213.136.105.62:80>
#\d[1].*:*\d


PROXY = " proxies" # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT
#PROXY = " 35.187.234.217:80" # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)

chrome = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
chrome.get("http://whatismyipaddress.com")



The regex is: \d[1].*:*\d
```

Attempted workaround with [Regex](https://pastebin.com/zyFd3nZW)

Answer (score 0):

I've found, that you can get IP and port from `Proxy` class using `tasks.result()[1].host` and `tasks.result()[1].port`.

Hope that helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
print('Found proxy: %s' % proxy)
```

to this:

```
return str(proxy.host) + ":" + str(proxy.port)
```

and make the `ProxyBroker` function and call it before webdrive like this:

```
def get_proxy(countries):
    import asyncio
    from proxybroker import Broker

    async def show(proxies):
        while True:
            proxy = await proxies.get()
            if proxy is None: break
            return str(proxy.host) + ":" + str(proxy.port)

    proxies = asyncio.Queue()
    broker = Broker(proxies)
    tasks = asyncio.gather(
        broker.find(types=['HTTPS'], countries=[countries], limit=1),
        show(proxies))

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(tasks)
```

The code will become something like this:

```
def get_proxy(countries):
    import asyncio
    from proxybroker import Broker

    async def show(proxies):
        while True:
            proxy = await proxies.get()
            if proxy is None: break
            return str(proxy.host) + ":" + str(proxy.port)

    proxies = asyncio.Queue()
    broker = Broker(proxies)
    tasks = asyncio.gather(
        broker.find(types=['HTTPS'], countries=[countries], limit=1),
        show(proxies))

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(tasks)

PROXY = get_proxy('US')" proxies" # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT
#PROXY = " 35.187.234.217:80" # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)

chrome = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
chrome.get("http://whatismyipaddress.com")
```